# Is America economy, Connecitcut's economy, and the global in general recovering and better than the year 2008?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, labor-economics, unemployment, political-economy

Please answer all three if you can.  I live in Connecticut, America, and of course global trade and economies matter as we are becoming more global from technology.

December 2007 the markets crashed hard and 2008-09 was the actual defined recession.  Worst we ever had (not depression, recession).  By GDP growth definition we did recover.  BUT living in Connecticut I've seen things differently so sorry if it sounds opinionated but I'm trying to put facts together from research and forum answers.

GE Headquarters is leaving CT and moving to Boston, meaning hundreds of high paid jobs leaving and the taxes are switched to everyone else yes?  Our governor has been called the worst, and we only have 3 million people which is down a lot in past years.  That means less business and money which is not good.  Taxes are already higher than almost every other state...BUT my question is are we recovering because form what I've read the answer is yes.  But if a huge job supplier is leaving and tax burdens increase, how can CT ever recover?

The same for America.  Unemployment is like 5% but most of these jobs at least where I am on the East Coast are part time fast food/retail jobs.  Good for kids maybe, but full time employment and good pay even start at $11 or $12 an hour is better than a father supporting his family on a 20 hour a week mcdonalds fry cook.  So is this really a recovery (maybe definition) but has it really gotten better?

Not just here...but the rest of the world as well?  All I hear is bad stuff about Europe, debt crisis, Greece.  What's going on?  No blame game what is going on for sure that we know?

Comment: FRED says for Connecticut since 2002: [Unemployment](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=jrTF), [Total non-farm employees](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=jrTG), [Real total GDP](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=jrTH), [Real median household income](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=jrTI), [Resident population](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=jrTJ).  Take your pick